# Using the latest version of google closure with clojurescript?

Tags: leiningen, google-closure, clojurescript

How would I get clojurescript and lein-cljsbuild to use the newest version of the google closure instead of last year's version? I would like to use the new features such as the websockets abstraction layer.

I have tried making a jar of the latest copy and installing that using lein-localrepo, but it doesn't seem to have any affect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I just noticed this after some googling: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/clojure/kzzBoCZiAx0

Is there a way to use it in lein-cljsbuild (I don't mind including the 3rd party tools)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different version of the Google Closure compiler simply by excluding its dependency from Clojurescript in your project.clj and adding another version. Here is an alternate version of [the example project that comes with lein cljs-build](https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild/blob/0.3.4/example-projects/simple/project.clj) using the latest version of Clojurscript and the Google Closure compiler.

```
(defproject cljsbuild-example-simple "0.3.4"
  :description "A simple example of how to use lein-cljsbuild"
  :source-paths ["src-clj"]
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [com.google.javascript/closure-compiler "v20131014"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-1934"
                  :exclusions [org.apache.ant/ant
                               com.google.javascript/closure-compiler]]
                 [compojure "1.0.4"]
                 [hiccup "1.0.0"]]
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "0.3.4"]
            [lein-ring "0.7.0"]]
  :cljsbuild {
    :builds [{:source-paths ["src-cljs"]
              :compiler {:output-to "resources/public/js/main.js"
                         :optimizations :whitespace
                         :pretty-print true}}]}
  :ring {:handler example.routes/app})
```

Which results in this dependency tree:

```
 [clojure-complete "0.2.3" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
 [com.google.javascript/closure-compiler "v20131014"]
   [args4j "2.0.16"]
   [com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305 "1.3.9"]
   [com.google.guava/guava "15.0"]
   [com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java "2.4.1"]
   [org.json/json "20090211"]
 [compojure "1.0.4"]
   [clout "1.0.1"]
   [org.clojure/core.incubator "0.1.0"]
   [org.clojure/tools.macro "0.1.0"]
   [ring/ring-core "1.1.0"]
     [clj-time "0.3.7"]
       [joda-time "2.0"]
     [commons-codec "1.6"]
     [commons-fileupload "1.2.1"]
     [commons-io "2.1"]
     [javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]
 [hiccup "1.0.0"]
 [org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-1934" :exclusions [[org.apache.ant/ant] [com.google.javascript/closure-compiler]]]
   [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.3"]
   [org.clojure/google-closure-library "0.0-20130212-95c19e7f0f5f"]
     [org.clojure/google-closure-library-third-party "0.0-20130212-95c19e7f0f5f"]
   [org.clojure/tools.reader "0.7.9"]
   [org.mozilla/rhino "1.7R4"]
 [org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.3" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
```

Then compile it:

```
$ lein cljsbuild once
Compiling ClojureScript.
Compiling "resources/public/js/main.js" from ["src-cljs"]...
Successfully compiled "resources/public/js/main.js" in 9.181874 seconds.
```

Hope this helps!